# Resources For Guava

Tags: java, guava

I've noticed that the Apache Commons library has 3 books out on it. Is there a book on the Guava library?

The library seems to include quite a lot, however I can't seem to find a consistent guide that does a good overview+benchmarks on the entire library and how its written.

Comment: No book that I'm aware of. (And the Commons books aren't particularly up to date.)

Comment: At least they give you a historical starting point. Which is all you can ask for on books that deal with libraries.

Comment: The Javadoc's pretty good, and the library's pretty small - what would you want in a book?  The library's so small, in fact, that it's one of the few that I've skimmed the Javadoc end to end.

Comment: The javadoc is a very low level and very close view of the library. I'm looking for a book to at least give some since of history and overview of what the library is and where to find things. For example there used to be a big recommendation for MapMaker, then it was ConcurrentLinkedHashMap, and now its CacheBuilder.

Comment: The library changes tend to come in waves. In your example, CLHM was my side project that I brought into Google and helped ramp up the Guava team on algorithmic techniques wrt caching. That evolution is described in these [slides](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf). The best resource is to monitor the users group, blogs, and presentations. Guava is the combination of numerous contributors, with a team that ensures the APIs are consistent, allowing it to continuously evolve.

Comment: It was actually this precise SO question that inspired http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained, which is now a pretty comprehensive wiki.

Comment: Thanks!! :) Can I put that on my resume? I inspired the guava team! :P

Comment: @Louis - thanks for the link, looks like a great resource.  Also, Tim O'Brien has written a few chapters on Guava (I/O and Collections) that I found useful.  They give a good overview of the functionality, examples, and discussion.  http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/guava-io-sect-flush-close.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but the old [Netflix tutorial](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/Guava_for_Netflix_.pdf) covers a lot of it. It's a great read and it's worth it for this picture alone:

[image]

Update: these days there is a manual, [Guava Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained)

Comment: You got my upvote just for the screenshot.